# Wordpress shortcode acceps only default attributes

Tags: php, wordpress, shortcode

The problem is that when I insert my shortcode into PageBuilder only the default value is excepted. The code is like this:

```
function Insert_Download($attr) {
    $z = shortcode_atts(array(
        'link_file' => 'xxxx',
        'link_class' => 'e-countries__link',
        'svg_path' => '#download',
        'svg_class' => 'e-countries__link-svg'
    ), $attr);
    $download = '<a class="'. esc_attr($z["link_class"]) . '" href="'. get_template_directory_uri(). '/' . esc_attr($z["link_file"]) . '" download>' . esc_html__('Download', 'fbstax-theme') . '<svg class="' . esc_attr($z["svg_class"]) .'" style="width:20px; height: 20px; margin-left: 20px"><use xlink:href=' . get_template_directory_uri(). '/img/svg/sprite.svg' . esc_attr($z["svg_path"]) . '></use></svg>'.'</a>';
    return $download;
}
add_shortcode( 'InsertDownload', 'Insert_Download' );
```

So in my PageBuilder I insert this

```
[InsertDownload linkPath='downloads/poland/code_of_commercial_companies_in_poland.pdf']
```

But outcome  attribute href looks like like this:

```
href="http://my.localclean.my/wp-content/themes/fbstax-theme/xxxx"
```

What is wrong?

Comment: you made a typo here. Replace **linkPath** to **link_file** in the line
[InsertDownload linkPath='downloads/poland/code_of_commercial_companies_in_poland.pdf']

Comment: `linkPath or link_file`?

Comment: as @Sumit noticed, you don't have `linkPath` attribute in your shortcode.typo is here: `So in my PageBuilder I insert this

[InsertDownload linkPath='downloads/poland/code_of_commercial_companies_in_poland.pdf']`. so instead use this one: `[InsertDownload link_file='downloads/poland/code_of_commercial_companies_in_poland.pdf']`

Comment: Guys, thank you very much. It was so obvious! )) Sometimes you look at the code in search of more complicated things but can't notice the simplest thing! Also as I've tested linkPath will not work because due to docs name must be only lowercase or underscore. So one more interesting tip to know ) Thanks one more time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You replace linkPath to link_file

```
[InsertDownload link_file='downloads/poland/code_of_commercial_companies_in_poland.pdf']
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It was so obvious! )) Sometimes you look at the code in search of more complicated things but can't notice the simplest thing! Also as I've tested linkPath will not work because due to docs name must be only lowercase or underscore. So one more interesting tip to know ) Thanks one more time!